# how to display all articles published under a tag in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags

I am trying to show all articles published under a tag( currently, tags are displaying on article index page). I can fetch all tags on article index page. But those tags are not have any article with them.In db, there is relation between tag and article table which are posted below. Please suggest me how to display all the articles under a tag on article index page.

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :is_user_admin, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :destroy]

    def is_user_admin
      redirect_to(action: :index) unless current_user.try(:is_admin?) 
      return false 
    end

      def index
          @articles = Article.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
      @article_titles = Article.first(10)
      @tags = Tag.all
      end

    def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

      def new
      @article = Article.new
      end
    end
```

tags_controller.rb

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
 #before_filter :user_signed_in, only: [:destroy]

   def index
    @tags = Tag.all
   end

    def show
     @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130411074056) do

  create_table "articles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "taggings", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  add_index "taggings", ["article_id"], :name => "index_taggings_on_article_id"
  add_index "taggings", ["tag_id"], :name => "index_taggings_on_tag_id"

  create_table "tags", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
```

article/index.html.erb(where I need to display tags and under those articles)

```
 <% if !@tags.nil? %>
           <% @tags.each  do | tags | %>

           <div style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:8px"> <%= link_to tags.name, "/path1"  %></div>
           <% end%>
           <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the relationship between Article and Tag has been properly defined as [has_many :through => :taggings](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many), as such:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles, :through => :taggings
end
```

and that the result should be formatted as shown in the following sample:

```
Tag 1
  Article 1
  Article 2
  Article 3
Tag 2
  Article 2
  Article 4
```

Use the following code in *articles/index.html.erb* to display the articles which belong to each tag:

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag %>
  <% tag.articles.each do |article| %>
    <%= link_to article.title, article %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hi sunxperous, thanks for your reply. Your suggestion was nearly close one that i am looking for. Exactly i want to display all tags in db on article index page and when click on any tag, it will display all articles published under it. I do not want to show articles under tags like you suggest. any suggestion would be appriciated .

Comment: hi Sunxperous, I want like this- Tag1, Tag2, Tag3 and when any of these tag will be clicked, will show us articles published under them.

Comment: In order to achieve that in _articles/index_, you will need to make use of Ajax or Javascript. Without which, it will be easier to use the show action in TagsController to achieve what you want, i.e. /tags/1 to display articles for Tag1, and /tags/2 to display the articles for Tag2.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Article 
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
  ....
end
class Taggings
  belongs_to :articles
  belongs_to :tags
  ...
end
class Tags
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :articles, :through => :taggings
  ...
end
```

Now you can get all the tags of the article by `@article.tags` and all articles in a tag by `@tag.articles`

For additional info, refer guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: hi manoj, thanks for your replay. When I tried  <% @tag.articles.each do |tag_articles| %>
            <%= tag_articles.title %>
           <% end %>, I got NoMethodError in Articles#index
Any suggestions.
Showing /Users/harshaldhumal/Desktop/kuta/billi/app/views/articles/index.htm

undefined method `articles' for nil:NilClass error.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution. I is similar to Sunxperous. I implemented like this:- <% @tags.each do |tag| %>
           <%= link_to tag.name, tag, :class => "tag" %>
         <% end %>. As I already have index and show action in tag controller .In "show.html.erb of tag, I did like this-:   <% @tag.articles.each do |article| %>

<%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %>